How to view the library variables value which are protected or locked in azure devops?
I want make use same Locked library variables value in another project, Since the person entered in first place is not available now.
I tried using print value, but it does not work
if anyone have idea How to view the library variables value which are protected or locked in azure devops ?
Please help me

Did any of the below answers helped solve your problem?

You cannot get the values of variables set as secret in a variable group - at least not directly.
There's a good reason for that: secret variables can be used for private information like passwords, IDs, and other identifying data that you wouldn't want exposed in a pipeline.
Recommended approach
If your Azure DevOps organization is linked to an Azure subscription, consider storing your secrets in an Azure key vault and link it to a variable group, instead of storing secrets directly in the variable group.
This allows you to access the secret values - e.g. for troubleshooting purposes, etc.
Also, Azure Key Vault provides among other things: auditability;
secret rotation; centralized management; monitoring and alerting (e.g.,
using Azure Event Grid and Logic Apps to send notifications when secrets are expiring).


I tried using print value, but it does not work.

In the log, the secret will show as *** to protect the secret.
As a workaround, we can iterate over each character in the secret and print it line by line using the echo command. This way the secret will not show as ***.
For example, I have a secret and the value is 123456. With the following yaml, it will print the value in log line by line.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- group: "variable group name"
steps:
- script: |
      echo $(secret)
      string=$(secret)
      for (( i=0; i<${#string}; i++ )); do
        echo "${string:$i:1}"
      done
  displayName: 'print the secret'

The log:

Please be careful not to use this method under normal circumstances, as it may cause secrets to be leaked.


How to view the library variables value which are protected or locked in azure devops

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly get the Secret Variable value in Azure DevOps.
To meet your requirement, we can output the secret variable value to a file in pipeline. Then we can use Publish Build Artifacts task to publish the output file to pipeline artifacts.
For example:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
- group: "variablegroup"
steps:
- powershell: |
   "var1:$(var1) var2:$(var2)"| Out-File $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\output.txt
  displayName: 'OutPut Secrect Variable'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\output.txt'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Finally, we can download the output.txt file in Pipeline artifacts to check the secret variable value. Refer to this doc about download artifacts


You can print an encoded version of your locked secret onto the console, then copy and convert it back in a local terminal. This way Azure DevOps will not detect and mask the secret in the logs. For example:
scriptType: pscore
scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
inlineScript: |
  $secretBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('$(lockedSecret)')
                  $encodedSecret = [Convert]::ToBase64String($secretBytes)
                  Write-Host "Base64 Encoded Secret: $encodedSecret"

In a terminal:
$s = "paste your encoded secret"
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($s))

